# AssertionError: assert <enum 'AccessId'> is str + where <enum 'AccessId'> = type(<AccessId.BUYLIST_TAB: 'Listes'>)

Tags: python, types, enums, assert

this is strange : my class is recognized as an Enum even tho i didn't inherite from it

```py
class AccessId:
    MENU_TAB: str = "Menu"
    BASKET_TAB: str = "Panier"
    BUYLIST_TAB: str = "Listes"
    HOME_TAB: str = "Accueil"
    DISCOUNT_TAB: str = "Promos"
    DELETE_PRODUCT: str = "Supprimer l'article"
```

I tried to debug with this assertion :

```py
assert type(AccessId.HOME_TAB) is str
```

And got :

```
AssertionError: assert <enum 'AccessId'> is str
 +  where <enum 'AccessId'> = type(<AccessId.HOME_TAB: 'Accueil'>)
```

I do not understand, please, someone, help me

*Things i tried :*

- Cleared `__pycache__` folders
- Tried with `assert type(AccessId.HOME_TAB.value) is str` since it's apparently an enum and it didn't find the attribute value.
- Tried in console `type(AccessId.HOME_TAB) is str` and got `True` wtf
- Created a similar class and got no AssertionError (???)

Comment: Those messages are not from the standard Python REPL -- are you using Jupyter, IPython, or something else?

Comment: I was using IPython, the problem is due to auto import, my IDE auto-imported a library from a the build directory instead of the one from the project and i didn't double-checked that...

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  You should answer your own question so someone in the future can benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why, please check if your IDE doesn't auto-import from the wrong directory. In my case, it was the build directory where i previously subclass Enum with AccessId.